# NSDate precision lost when transforming to NSNumber miliseconds

Tags: iphone, nsdate, precision

I want to obtain a NSDate like Date().getTime() in java, miliseconds since 1970
But when I do it, I lost precision and I get a different date

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSNumber *nowLong = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1000.0 * [nowDate timeIntervalSince1970]] retain];
NSLog(@"nowDate %@", nowDate);
NSLog(@"nowLong %f", [nowLong doubleValue]);

NSNumber *nowNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([nowLong doubleValue]/1000.0)];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [nowNumber doubleValue];
NSDate *nowDateFromLong = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
NSLog(@"nowDateFromLong %@", nowDateFromLong);
```

//Output console

nowDate 2012-03-23 18:34:42 +0000

nowLong 1332527628288.000000

nowDateFromLong 2012-03-23 18:33:48 +0000

I really need to get the date in miliseconds like java, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to double, not float:

> NSNumber *nowLong = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1000.0 * [nowDate
>   timeIntervalSince1970]] retain];

Comment: Ooops, thanks. I'm an idiot I've been debugging this all afternoon! Embarrased right now xD